# How do I ignore the routes of feature modules imported into a parent feature module which defines its own route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Given two feature modules (A,B) which each have their own routing modules, how do I import module B into A without having the route from B (/B) interfere with A (/A)? As it is, the route from B pushes onto the front of module A's routeConfig resulting in the component specified by (/B) loading.

Use case is that module B also exports a component I need within A (this is the same component that the Module B route specifies).

I suppose the straightforward solution is to simply create two modules for B, Bc which exports the component and Br which imports Bc and has its own routing module. In that case I would import Bc into A and issue would be avoided.

Is there another way to handle this case or is it simply that my current architecture is incorrect?

Comment: Finding the drive-by downvotes entirely unhelpful and irritating. I suspect the downvote was simply that no code was seen in the question thus it was assumed not to be a quality question. Ridiculous. Of course as there was no comment I can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try and understand this from an Architectural Standpoint.

If you have two feature modules, then to avoid any route conflicts, and also to make your App load faster, you should consider making both these modules lazy loaded.

If you have a Component, that is shared between two modules, then you should ideally place it in a shared module and then import the shared module in both modules(A and B).

If you have some single-use components, pipes, directives, etc. then you should place them in a core module and just import it once, inside your AppModule.

There are some extremely important guidelines similar to this, in **[Angular Styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)** which I recommend you to go through once.

Hope this helps you chose what you should be doing about the `shared` component.

Comment: Your answer seems to reiterate my fallback plan . I suppose this confirms architecture needs to be refactored to support both use cases for component B.